# Google Drive to be used as our SaaS storage

Tags: amazon-s3, google-drive-api

I've seen the recently Google Drive pricing changes and they are amazing.

- 1Tb in Google Drive = $9.99
- 1Tb in Amazon S3 = $85 ($43 if you have more than 5000TB with them)

This changes everything !

We have a SaaS website in which we keep customer's files. Does anyone know if Google Drive can be used to keep this kind of files/service or it's just for personal use?

Does it have a robust API for uploading, downloading, and create public URL's to access files as S3 have ?

Edit: I saw the SDK here (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/). The main concern is if this service can be used for keeping customer's files, I mean, a SaaS website offering a service and keeping files there.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't really change anything.

> **“**Google Drive storage is for users and Google Cloud Storage is for developers.**”**
>
> — https://support.google.com/a/answer/2490100?hl=en

The analogous service with comparable functionality to S3 is Google Cloud Storage, which is remarkably similar to S3 in pricing.

https://developers.google.com/storage/pricing

Answer (score 2):

**Does anyone know if Google Drive can be used to keep this kind of files/service or it's just for personal use?**

Yes you can. That's exactly why the Drive SDK exists. You can either store files under the user's own account, or under an "app" account called a Service Account.

**Does it have a robust API for uploading, downloading, and create public URL's to access files as S3 have ?**

"Robust" is a bit subjective, but there is certainly an API.

There are a number of techniques you can use to access the stored files. Look at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files to see the various URLs which are provided.

Por true public access, you will probably need to have the files under a public directory. See https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

**NB. If you are in the TB space, be very aware that Drive has a bunch of quotas, some of which are unpublished. Make sure you test any proof of concept at full scale.**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to spoil your party, before you get too excited, [look at this issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/drive/meet-the-community/9vwVzDhwKSM). It is in Google's own product, and has been active since November 2013 (i.e.4 months). Now imagine re-syncing a few hundred GB of files once a while. Or better, ask your customers to do it with their files after you recommended Drive to them.